# Ошибка при использовании delete[]

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Скажите почему компилятор (Visual Studio 2015) выдаёт ошибку при использовании `delete[]`. Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");

    char* str = "heLLoWorld";
    const int len = strlen(str);

    char *ptr = new char[len];
    ptr = str;
    cout << ptr << endl;
    delete[] ptr; // операция освобождения массива

}
```

Comment: На будущее, если у Вас какая-то ошибка - нужно вставлять её в тело вопроса, как мы можем догадаться, что Вы там за ошибку видите?

Comment: К тому же понятно, что в данном случае компилятор никакой ошибки не выдавал вообще. Ошибка в данном случае будет, разумеется, времени выполнения и к компилятору никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: Если вы пишете на C++, не пользуйтесь ручным распределением памяти. Оно сложное для новичков. Пользуйтесь строками языка C++ — `std::string`, там все операции ведут себя ожидаемо. Например, ваш код выглядел бы так: `string str = "heLLoWorld"; string ptr = str; cout << ptr << endl;`, выделение и уничтожение памяти не понадобилось.

Comment: Почему бы сразу не вывести строку в cout, к чему это странное стремление выделить память в куче, даже когда в этом нет смысла. cout << "helloWorld" << endl; Вообще конечно на удивление бессмысленный код в корневом посте, ни про одну из строк внутри main нельзя сказать что она имеет смысл.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сначала вы динамически выделили память и ее адрес сохранили в переменной `ptr`

```
char *ptr = new char[len];
```

Затем вы изменили значение этой переменной, присвоив ей адрес памяти, занимаемой строковым литералом

```
ptr = str;
```

После этого адрес динамически выделенной памяти стал утерянным, и у вас образовалась "утечка памяти", так как вы уже не в состоянии сами удалить ее за неимением ее адреса.

Затем вы попытались удалить память, занимаемую строковым литералом

```
delete[] ptr; // операция
```

Однако строковые литералы хранятся в статической области памяти программы, а не в динамической. Вы не можете применять оператор `delete []` (и `delete`) к указателю, если он не хранит адрес памяти, выделенной динамически с помощью оператора `new`

Именно поэтому возникла ошибка.

Я  думаю, что вы имели в виду следующее

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <clocale>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");

    const char* str = "heLLoWorld";
    size_t len = strlen( str );

    char *ptr = new char[len + 1];
    strcpy( ptr, str );

    cout << ptr << endl;

    delete[] ptr;
}
```

Обратите внимание, что функция `strlen` имеет тип возвращаемого значения `size_t`. Этот же тип имеет оператор-функция `new` для своего параметра, которая вызывается для выделения необходимой памяти.

Также строковые литералы в C++ имеют типы константных массивов. Поэтому указатели на символы строковых литералов также должны иметь квалификатор `const`.

Например

```
const char* str = "heLLoWorld";
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что `ptr = str;` - копирует указатели, а не массив; для копирования нужно использовать:

```
char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

Ну и здесь еще:

```
char *ptr = new char[len+1]; 
ptr[len] = '\0';
```

длина должна быть на единицу больше для завершающего символа '\0'